# tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale does not actually produce a grayscale image?

Tags: image, tensorflow, image-processing

Why is `tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale` not producing an actual grayscale image? Or is this just the "grayscale" image that is widely accepted?

[rgb_to_grayscale does not produce grayscale pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Xg5i.png)

```
input_images = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(target_images)
```

This is what I did to produce the input images. I'm not sure if I'm using it wrong but the tensorflow site did not really provide examples on how to use this function either. Am I missing a parameter or something to actually transform the pictures into grayscale?

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/data_augmentation#grayscale_an_image